# Правильное ли выражение "период времени"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, плеоназм

Часто можно увидеть (или услышать) выражение "за такой-то период времени" или "за такой-то временной период". Я сама употребила его в тексте, но потом задумалась, а нет ли здесь плеоназма: ведь период и без того временной, какой же еще?
То есть, либо "за такое-то время", либо "за такой-то период", так? Или такое выражение все-таки допустимо?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Видите ли, если мы посмотрим в толковые словари, то увидим у слова "период" почти десяток значений. И только в половине из них период – это "промежуток времени". Наверно, поэтому словосочетание "период времени" считается сейчас допустимым, это не стилистическая ошибка.

Answer (score 2):

Из книги **Голуб И.Б. "Стилистика русского языка"** (11-е изд. -- М.: Айрис-пресс, 2010):

[image]

Comment: >> Однако слово "период" постепенно приобрело значение "промежуток времени", и поэтому выражение "период времени" стало возможным.

Этого мне никогда не понять.

Comment: Niemand: "Этого мне никогда не понять".=== И мне тоже! Наверное, потому что я не Розенталь.  См. его: 

http://books.google.ru/books?id=idRfAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%22%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C&dq=%22%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%22%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=xWkwVKS7BKeaygO5xYLQAw&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBQ